# Have pronoun introductions spread to non-English-speaking communities/languages?

Tags: list-of-languages, sociolinguistics, pronouns, pragmatics

There seem to be two forms of these pronoun introductions, intended to promote [transfeminism](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/19359705.2011.553779), one voluntary/declarative and one interrogative:

For [an example](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/oct/11/cnn-chris-cuomo-apologizes-for-joke-gender-pronouns-kamala-harris) of a voluntary/declarative one:

> Kamala Harris introduced herself with ‘My pronouns are she, her and hers,’  [...] at an LGBTQ town hall.

As for [the interrogative](https://www.insidehighered.com/views/2018/09/19/why-asking-students-their-preferred-pronoun-not-good-idea-opinion)

> For many faculty members, the semester begins with the now-familiar call to students to “introduce yourself with your name and pronoun.”

Have these forms of pronoun introduction/interrogation spread outside mainly English-speaking countries?

Comment: In many languages the pronouns do not play the same role as in English where those are the only gendered bit of the language. Moreover, some languages use genders even in the first person. In Slavic languages if you say "Já jsem byla. Я была." or similar, it is clear you consider yourself grammatically feminine. In some of those languages surnames have different form for women and men so there is a reasonable way of guessing the preferred gender from the name the person is using. Introducing the pronoun would be quite bizzare and to me it looks like it that works only in certain languages.

Comment: @VladimirF: I agree the question/approach would not make sense in all languages (Hungarian and Finnish, in particular). But there surely are languages other than English in which it would make sense, e.g. German or Swedish, if I'm not mistaken. I'm simply asking if it's spread to some other language in which it *would be applicable*. Are you saying it would not be applicable in *any* other (major) language besides English?

Comment: This has caught on in Germany too. You can do a google search for "mein Pronomen" (with speech marks).

Comment: @fdb Nah, it hasn't yet really caught on. There is something to find but it is still on the very experimental level, and it is to a large extend only usable in written language, but not speakable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gender-neutral pronoun, *hen*, has recently [found its way into the official dictionary of Swedish](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/mar/24/sweden-adds-gender-neutral-pronoun-to-dictionary). It is a loanword from Finnish, [proposed in 1966 and popularised in the 2000s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Swedish). Transfeminism seems to be one of the reasons for its adoption. The use *hen* spread, to some degree, to other Scandinavian languages, such as Norwegian. Norwegian Wikipedia [lists](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kj%C3%B8nnsn%C3%B8ytralt_pronomen) *hen*, *hin*, *hyn* and *høn* as examples of gender-neutral pronouns that can be used instead of traditional *han* (he) and *hun* (she). The statement is unreferenced, so this particular list should be taken with a grain of salt, but it still shows that there is some pronoun variation of this kind in Norwegian.

To answer your question directly, there is such a thing as pronoun introductions in Scandinavia. NRK [reports](https://www.nrk.no/sorlandet/vil-sprette-sjampanjen-for-_hen_-og-_hin_-1.13362107) that sexologist Esben Esther Pirelli Benestad has fought for the right to be called *hin* and *hen* for many years, and the Norwegian Labour Party has standardising a gender-neutral pronoun in its political programme.

Comment: Well, the question as I understood it was not about the existence of neutral pronouns but about introducing yourself  with the pronouns or declaring them in your profile. See also other Fizz's question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46651/do-european-politicians-typically-put-their-pronouns-on-their-social-media-pages In that sense the fdb's comment is more on-topic. Another problem is, whether such a question is on-topic on this site...

Comment: I mean, it actually is about declaring the right pronoun for you, even when it is a normal gendered pronoun. The issue of existence of genderless pronouns is secondary here. Notice the example of Kamala Harris in the question. She requests a normal plain-old gendered "she, her and hers".

Comment: @VladimirF Well, given that it is known that Benestad wants to be called *hin* and/or *hen*, Benestad must have introduced them as their preferred pronouns. So the second paragraph is an answer to the question, which wasn't limited to gender pronouns. Perhaps you're right that the first paragraph is slightly off-topic, but I'll leave it, since it introduces some context.